# Circular dependency occurs when running Unit Test but not the NestJs app itself

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, nestjs, circular-dependency

I'm getting error when running unit tests in my NestJS project. But there is no error when running the project itself.

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading enumToDescription')

6 | export class ChannelUser {  
7 |   @ApiProperty({  
8 |     description: SwaggerHelper.enumToDescription(UserAccessEnum),
```

I found out that the problem is a circular dependency because `SwaggerHelper` is imported from `index.ts` file. I solved it with importing from the file itself instead of `index.ts` file.

But I want to know why this error happens just for testing?

This is my unit test:

```js
describe('Auth Service', () => {
  let authService: AuthService;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const testModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [UsersModule, GlobalModule],
    }).compile();
    authService = testModule.get(AuthService);
  });

  describe('Refresh token', () => {
    expect(authService.refreshTokens({token: '123'})).toBe('11');
  });
});
```

Comment: does the error occur when u do  `npm run build` ?

Comment: @itssajan There is no errors in `yarn build` or `yarn start`

Comment: @rostamiani its been a while but were you able to get a solution for this?